# Have 2 playback devices running(more in description)

Tags: windows-8, audio, desktop-computer, recording, headset

I need to have Elgato and my turtle beach px22 headset playing the same sounds both at the same time.
I really just need a way to get the computer's sounds while keep px22 as default allowing the control panel to change volume.
If I change it to the default speakers playing to this elgato sound I wont have any control over my headset?
Anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It randomly started working again after restarting with it set to record the default speakers in the recorder settings.

In the recording I had it set to listen to the default playback device (my headset).  I also disabled Intel display audio before restart.

I have no clue why it fixed itself, but it works perfect now!  Hope if you have the same issue this helps.

I found out how you do this (it's kind of a glitch):

1. Set your recorder to use sound coming from the HDMI.
2. Set in your sound setting to have your headset as default.
3. In your sound recording settings set stereo mix to default and to listen to your headset.
4. Disable your driver Intel display audio (disable the driver putting sound into that HDMI).
5. Restart your PC.
6. Go into your recorder settings and change it back to your Intel speakers.

> Your recorder or whatever you set to use speakers can now get all sounds from your PC while having your headset as the default, allowing control.
>
> > For the mix just set the mic setting to the mic you want to use.  Example:

[image: example]

> > > Extra Note: If you don't have Intel speakers try to use your default sound system.

Edit: The game volume levels are very low for me after I accidentally messed with somthing.

Other than the glitch that I found, I also found a [real answer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UEk1mlWVck). This allows me to control my headset and send sound to the elgato.